# Why aren't my addons visible in the side bar (N-bar)?

Tags: interface, add-on

I recently updated Blender from 2.83 to 3.1. On 3.1 my addons are not appearing in my sidebar. In Edit > preferences, they are checked and I should be able to use them but I have no way to access them. Is there a way to put them on the sidebar/get to them a different way?

They are not visible in Edit or Object mode.

Comment: Did you check that they are compatible with 3.1? There were quite a few internal changes in Blender between versions 2.8 and 3 so they might not work in 3.1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.